# Using 'For Loop' in Java Example

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, while-loop

I'm doing an exercise in Java. This is using on `for` Loop. The code below shows `while` Loop. This is 'Beer Song' example.

```
int beerNum = 99;
String word = "bottles";
while (beerNum > 0) {
   if (beerNum == 1) {
       word = "bottle";
   }
   System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
   System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
   System.out.println("Take one down.");
   System.out.println("Pass it around.");
   beerNum = beerNum -1;
   if (beerNum > 0) {
      System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
   }
   else {
      System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
   }
} // end loop
```

And the output is:

```
OUTPUT:
-------------
99 bottles of beer on the wall
99 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
98 bottles of beer on the wall
98 bottles of beer on the wall
98 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
97 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
----------
----------
---------
---------

2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
1 bottles of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
No more bottles of beer on the wall
```

the output above shows that when the song ends with 1 bottle of beer it will then says "No more bottles of beer on the wall".

Now my task is to take this 'Beer Song' example and rewrite it using a `for` Loop rather than an while loop.

I did that but the output looks does not match output with the while loop.
Here's the code and output using `for` Loop.

```
 String word = "bottles";
 for(int beerNum = 99; beerNum > 0; beerNum --) {
     if(beerNum==1) {
         word = "bottle";
     }
     System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
     System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
     System.out.println("Take one down.");
     System.out.println("Pass it around.");
     beerNum = beerNum -1;
     if (beerNum > 0) {
        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
     }

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output

99 bottles of beer on the wall
99 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
98 bottles of beer on the wall
97 bottles of beer on the wall (should be 98)
97 bottles of beer   (should be 98)
Take one down.
Pass it around.
96 bottles of beer on the wall 
95 bottles of beer on the wall (should be 96)
95 bottles of beer (should be 96)
Take one down.
Pass it around.
94 bottles of beer on the wall 
93 bottles of beer on the wall (should be 94)
93 bottles of beer (should be 94)
Take one down.
Pass it around.
--------------
--------------
--------------
    4 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer on the wall (should be 4)
3 bottles of beer (should be 4)
Take one down.
Pass it around.
2 bottles of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer on the wall (should be 2)
1 bottle of beer  (should be 2)
Take one down.
Pass it around.
No more bottles of beer on the wall
```

The output is not showing right using `for` Loop. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check where you are decrementing the variable. You might find it being done twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the `for` loop the variable is already being decremented. (`for(int beerNum = 99; beerNum > 0; beerNum --)` Emphasis on the `beerNum--` part)

So the statement `beerNum = beerNum -1;` will decremented twice. You need to remove this line.

```
String word = "bottles";
for(int beerNum = 99; beerNum > 0; beerNum --) {
     if(beerNum==1) {
         word = "bottle";
    }
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
    System.out.println("Take one down.");
    System.out.println("Pass it around.");
    if (beerNum > 1) {
       System.out.println(beerNum -1 + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
    } else {
       System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed 'beerNum = beerNum -1;'. The output shows exactly what I expected. But it missing something.when the song ends with 1 bottle of beer it does not show  "No more bottles of beer on the wall".

Comment: @AzizBokhari That is because `beerNum` is decremented at the end of the loop. To fix this you can simply do `if(beerNum > 1) {//pint how many bottles}`

Comment: In the second if, it should be `(beerNum-1)`, not `beerNum`, to make it "look like" it has been decremented (and the singularization should happen there).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.  Got the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You are decreasing the *beerNum* variable **twice** in your for loop code. First in the loop header, then again in the loop body.

That is all there is to this.